# Hide part view text in overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I making bookReader and one page will fit to user viewport. For this approach i make div

```
<div id="book">Long text...</div>
```

with

```
#book { 
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Then i provide to scroll this element only with buttons next and prev. When user click next button it will scroll like this

```
$('#next').on('click',function(){
    $('#book').scrollTop($('#book').scrollTop() +  $('#book').height());
});
```

But i have problem. That some times user will see part of text-line. How can i check every page is that last text-line is shown broken, and hide them if him is broken. I don't want to change content. I need a function that will check every page if that contains that part text and if this have that part text, hide him by making on the top element that should hide that.

DEMO: I show in red color what i need find and hide.

http://jsfiddle.net/lvivgeorge/jd7mum6c/3/

DEMO 2: It can contains anything (header tags, img, `<code>` , etc.)
http://jsfiddle.net/lvivgeorge/jd7mum6c/12/

P.S. Make all the same `line-height` is not solution. Change content styles is not solution too.

Comment: what does this mean? Only scroll to top of red highlights?

Comment: No change scroll, and no change content, i need function that will check is that have that part text and if have hide him by making on the top element that should hide them

Answer (score 1):

IMHO You should set fixed `line-height` of each text line, and set container height fixed as a multiple height of each textline. This should helps

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/jd7mum6c/5/

Comment: I have try something like that, but if book contains `h1,h2,img` or some thing like that tags, and it not always good approach.

Comment: It's not flexible. What will happen when I try to read from mobile device?

Comment: So another solutions can be add fade in / fade out gradient on top / bottom of container

Comment: It's no problem it containes h1, h2 or anything else. Just simply force #book * {line-height: ...} on each element. In case of images You can try to scale it to specific height. Also same on tables

Comment: I want something like that , but how i can know what height would be of that 'fade out gradient on to'. I can't change content, and content style.

Comment: If the question is about showing only a part of a text of line in the vertical direction (I thought it was about not having a sentence split over multiple pages) this is the only option. Create a good [vertical rhythm and baseline](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/17/css-baseline-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/) and make every element (e.g. `h1` and `img`) be a multiple of that.

Comment: You can decide what will be height of fade gradient. But then You shouldn't do scroll of whole height of content (80-90% I think would be better) and You should change your navigation from left/right to bottom/up

Comment: If contents will contain header it would broke http://jsfiddle.net/lvivgeorge/jd7mum6c/11/

Comment: Yes, but You can go like that http://jsfiddle.net/jd7mum6c/14/ Of course You can set 10px as base, to get better gradiation effect

Comment: I don't want to change content, i want hide that part text only, and show him in next page

Comment: You shouldn't make everything the same `line-height`. You should make sure that every element will fit inside a multiple of a fixed height. For example regular text at 16px with a line-height of 1.5 takes up 24px. Perhaps make a `<h1>` take up 48px by giving it a `font-size: 24px`, `line-height: 1.5`, `margin-top: 8px` & `margin-bottom: 4px`. See http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/qENzJJ